# How to do statistics on the values extracted from HTTP response header in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to test my web server, instead of using the jmeter's default 
 response time, I'd rather to use one specific header value that I extracted from response header by Regular Expression Extractor, how can Jmeter generate a table or graph base on that value(think that value as the real response time)

Answer (score 0):

Use [sample_Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) to generate the required data with simple data writer as csv. Then, replace the response time data generated in that sheet with your custom variable data in the sheet. Then, browser that file in the listeners as per your requirement.